# Install SQL Server 2000 from Install Shield 2009 Premier

Tags: crystal-reports, installation, sql-server-2000, installshield

I have a basic MSI project in InstallShield 2009 Premier. I have some files(dlls, exes) to be copied, no problem. But what I need to install SQL Server 2000 in addition to this. What I did during development time was to install SQL Server 2000 before development(C#.net). I saw re-distributable "Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Desktop Engine (MSDE 2000) SP3a" (need to be downloaded). But would the installation of this re-distributable do the same job as SQL Server 2000?

Any information about installing "SQL Server 2000" from InstallShield... ?

Same question for installation of "Crystal Reports 2007".

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, adding SQL Server (or Crystal Reports) as a Redistributable should accomplish the same objective, as long as you choose the minimum-required version of SQL server that your application needs.